# Find element in array due to it's occurence in said array

Tags: arrays, c, counter

I have an issue where I need to find an element within the array and return that array element with the occurrence that it's at, along with the index. This must be done in a modified sequential search algorithim.

For instance, I have an array of {5, 6, 5, 3, 5}, and the user input occ(occurrence) = 2, key = 5, in this case, the program would return an output such as "The value 5 has an occurrence of 2 at index 2"

I have written code that loops through the array, finds the desired values and stores them in a count function, but am unsure on how to get my desired result.

My function code is as follows:

```
int findOccurrence(int arr[], int n, int occ, int k)
{
    int i, count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == k)
        {
            printf("Value %d occurred for the %dth time at index %d\n", k, count+1, i);
            count++;
            continue;

        } else if (count == 0){
            printf("Value %d not found in the array.", k);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(occ == i){
            printf("\nThe value %d has an occurrence of %d at index %d in the array.\n", k, occ, i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

I somehow got it to work earlier but with inconsistent results, so continued trying to solve the problem and came to this code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thank you

Comment: `if(arr[i] == k) { count++; if (count == occ) { printf("The value %d has an occurrence of %d at index %d", k, occ, i); } return; }` That is, just do the print and return as soon as the number of occurrences has been reached. Then if you get to the end of the first `for` loop without returning it means the number of occurrences has not been reached.

Comment: can you elaborate what is your desired output?

Comment: Why are you testing count every loop?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kaylum's comment I got to my desired result. In the end, all I had to do change the if `if(occ == i)` to `if(count == occ)` and move it up into the first for loop.

The working code is as follows:

```
int findOccurrence(int arr[], int n, int occ, int k)
{

    int i, count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == k)
        {
            printf("Value %d occurred for the %dth time at index %d\n", k, count, i+1);
            count++;
            continue;
        }

        if(count == occ)
        {
            printf("The value %d has an occurrence of %d at index %d in the array.\n", k, occ, i);
            break;
        } 
    }
}
```

Big thanks to Kaylum for the comment!

Comment: Your function is supposed to return an integer value but return statement is missing from it. Also, don't print the message in the function, rather return index where the `k` occurred for `occ`th time and based on return value print the message in caller function. With this, you can easily take care of case where the `k` is not exists in the given array.

Comment: That is not quite right. Test it on an array `{ 1, 1, 1}` with occ=2 and k=1. I think you'll find it does not print the desired output because the `continue` causes it to not do the following `count==occ` check. Remove the `continue`.